# Shipment Methods disappear

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, onepage-checkout, shipment, ce-1.8.0.0

I do have 3 shipment methods set up in the admin and set to Active: Tables Rates, Free Shipping and Flatrate.

After adding a product to the cart and going to the One Page Checkout, all three are being listed. When I check "Flatrate", click through to the Order summary, and go back to the shipping method to choose another one and again proceed to the Order summary, it tells me that the shipping method is invalid - all of a sudden - when `checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod` is fired.

This error is triggered in `public function saveShippingMethod($shippingMethod)` because `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRateByCode($shippingMethod);`
is not returning a `$rate`.

What's weird is that even though I selected Flat Rate Shipping it didn't list the Flatrate shipping costs in the order summary.

After reloading the one-page checkout page, the only shipping method available is "Free shipping". The others are gone.

I'm running Magento 1.8.0 and I'm out of ideas.

The `system.log` and `exception.log` are empty. Changing the theme to the `modern` default theme doesn't have any effect. Anyone can confirm this behavior in Magento 1.8.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really explain why it didn't work, but the solution for me was to disable free shipping, and all other shipping methods havn't disappeared ever again.

That seems to be a bug in Magento 1.8 and table rates shipping. Can anyone confirm this?